# Prestashop 1.7 удалить поле страны и фамилии в заказе

Tags: prestashop-1.7

При удалении в Интернационализация->География->Страны->Россия.

Входит такая ошибка в режиме отладки  [PrestaShopException]

Свойство Address->city пусто.
at line 944 in file classes/ObjectModel.php

```
     $message = $this->validateField($field, $this->$field);
942.             if ($message !== true) {
943.                 if ($die) {
944.                     throw new PrestaShopException($message);
945.                 }
946.                 return $error_return ? $message : false;
947.             }
948.         }
```

А без отладки 500 Internal server error 
когда возвращаю город или фамилию все работает отлично